# How to print all values specific of a key?

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to print all values associated a one key, for example:

Search by marcus, I'd like to return 5 lines.

Dict:

```
marcus {'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:49:33', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
fabin {'TIME': 'Mar  3 00:20:16', 'CONNECTION': 'login'}
marcus {'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:49:29', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
peter {'TIME': 'Mar  3 13:36:16', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
marcus {'TIME': 'Mar  3 14:28:56', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
peter {'TIME': 'Mar  3 02:17:34', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
marcus {'TIME': 'Mar  3 18:12:50', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
fabin {'TIME': 'Mar  3 22:50:15', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
peter {'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:14:16', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
marcus {'TIME': 'Mar  3 08:19:17', 'CONNECTION': 'login'}
peter {'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:16:45', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
fabin {'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:30:10', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
carl {'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:49:33', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
```

I dont know, if it is the most simple way, but is only return the last line.

```
for k,v in dict.items():
 if user in k:
  print v

output: marcus {'TIME': 'Mar  3 08:19:17', 'CONNECTION': 'login'}
```

Comment: How is the dict variable constructed in your code, because this doesnt seem valid. Also, you are overriding the built-in dict function with the dict variable (not causing this issue though)

Comment: If you have a dictionary, it can't have the same key twice, so you are only going to get one key that matches.  Show a working example.  That isn't Python dictionary syntax.  Also `if k == user:` would be more accurate, or `'marcusxyz'` and `'xyzmarcus'` would match user `'marcus'`  when using `in`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen What is the better way to create a list or dict in which I can use username to associate an informations? How you see my example, this dict stores a log, so when I search a name it should be return all lines.

Comment: @ThiagoL I gave an option below, but if you want one name to return all information, store the information in a list.  I'll update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have been adding items to a dictionary, and a dictionary can only have unique keys.  Consider:

```
D = {'marcus':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:49:33', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'},
     'fabin':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 00:20:16', 'CONNECTION': 'login'},
     'marcus':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:49:29', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'},
     'peter':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 13:36:16', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'},
     'marcus':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 14:28:56', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'},
     'peter':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 02:17:34', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'},
     'marcus':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 18:12:50', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'},
     'fabin':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 22:50:15', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'},
     'peter':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:14:16', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'},
     'marcus':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 08:19:17', 'CONNECTION': 'login'},
     'peter':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:16:45', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'},
     'fabin':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:30:10', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'},
     'carl':{'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:49:33', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}}

for k,v in D.items():
    print(k,v)
    if k == 'marcus':
        print(v)
```

Output (matches described behavior):

```
{'TIME': 'Mar  3 08:19:17', 'CONNECTION': 'login'}
```

Though it looks like there are multiples, a dictionary is only going to keep the last entry of a unique key.  If you need multiple instances of the same name, you need a different structure.  Instead of a (suspected) dict of dicts, use a list of dicts:

```
L = [{'NAME':'marcus','TIME':'Mar  3 15:49:33','CONNECTION':'logout'},
     {'NAME':'fabin','TIME':'Mar  3 00:20:16','CONNECTION':'login'},
     {'NAME':'marcus','TIME':'Mar  3 15:49:29','CONNECTION':'logout'},
     {'NAME':'peter','TIME':'Mar  3 13:36:16','CONNECTION':'logout'},
     {'NAME':'marcus','TIME':'Mar  3 14:28:56','CONNECTION':'logout'},
     {'NAME':'peter','TIME':'Mar  3 02:17:34','CONNECTION':'logout'},
     {'NAME':'marcus','TIME':'Mar  3 18:12:50','CONNECTION':'logout'},
     {'NAME':'fabin','TIME':'Mar  3 22:50:15','CONNECTION':'logout'},
     {'NAME':'peter','TIME':'Mar  3 15:14:16','CONNECTION':'logout'},
     {'NAME':'marcus','TIME':'Mar  3 08:19:17','CONNECTION':'login'},
     {'NAME':'peter','TIME':'Mar  3 15:16:45','CONNECTION':'logout'},
     {'NAME':'fabin','TIME':'Mar  3 15:30:10','CONNECTION':'logout'},
     {'NAME':'carl','TIME':'Mar  3 15:49:33','CONNECTION':'logout'}]

for d in L:
    if d['NAME'] == 'marcus':
        print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'NAME': 'marcus', 'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:49:33', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
{'NAME': 'marcus', 'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:49:29', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
{'NAME': 'marcus', 'TIME': 'Mar  3 14:28:56', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
{'NAME': 'marcus', 'TIME': 'Mar  3 18:12:50', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
{'NAME': 'marcus', 'TIME': 'Mar  3 08:19:17', 'CONNECTION': 'login'}
```

Another option is a dict of lists, appending each infodict in the value of the user key:

```
D = {'marcus':[{'TIME':'Mar  3 15:49:33','CONNECTION':'logout'},
               {'TIME':'Mar  3 15:49:29','CONNECTION':'logout'},
               {'TIME':'Mar  3 14:28:56','CONNECTION':'logout'},
               {'TIME':'Mar  3 18:12:50','CONNECTION':'logout'},
               {'TIME':'Mar  3 08:19:17','CONNECTION':'login'}],
     'fabin':[{'TIME':'Mar  3 00:20:16','CONNECTION':'login'},
              {'TIME':'Mar  3 22:50:15','CONNECTION':'logout'},
              {'TIME':'Mar  3 15:30:10','CONNECTION':'logout'}],
     'peter':[{'TIME':'Mar  3 13:36:16','CONNECTION':'logout'},
              {'TIME':'Mar  3 02:17:34','CONNECTION':'logout'},
              {'TIME':'Mar  3 15:14:16','CONNECTION':'logout'},
              {'TIME':'Mar  3 15:16:45','CONNECTION':'logout'}],
     'carl':[{'TIME':'Mar  3 15:49:33','CONNECTION':'logout'}]}

for item in D['marcus']:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
{'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:49:33', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
{'TIME': 'Mar  3 15:49:29', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
{'TIME': 'Mar  3 14:28:56', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
{'TIME': 'Mar  3 18:12:50', 'CONNECTION': 'logout'}
{'TIME': 'Mar  3 08:19:17', 'CONNECTION': 'login'}
```